# Graph with nine edges and all vertices of degree three

Tags: graph-theory

There is a graph with nine edges and all vertices of degree three?

I don't think that this graph exists, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: There is such a graph: it looks like a hexagon with all three diagonals.

Comment: You can also draw it as $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: I have more general question associated with this issue. Namely, for which $n$ graph with this property exists, where $n$ is a number of vertices? We already know that $9$ is such a number.

Comment: Which property are you thinking about - that all vertices have the same degree, that all vertices have degree $3$ or what?

Comment: If all vertices have the same degree and this is 3, these are the cubic graphs. See e.g. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_simple_cubic_graphs Wikipedia], which shows the 2 graphs with 9 edges (6 vertices).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this graph clearly exists.

[image]